# Listen to end of animation event for ViewAnimator

Tags: android

I have the following `ViewAnimator`

```
<ViewAnimator
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:id="@+id/view_animator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateFirstView="true">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/setup_password_select_type"
        layout="@layout/setup_password_select_type" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/setup_password_pattern"
        layout="@layout/setup_password_pattern" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/setup_password_pincode"
        layout="@layout/setup_password_pincode" />


</ViewAnimator>
```

I perform animation in the following way.

```
viewAnimator.setInAnimation(slideInRightFast);
viewAnimator.setOutAnimation(slideOutLeftSlow);
viewAnimator.setDisplayedChild(1);
```

I was wondering, how can I listen to end of animation event?

I tried to use

```
this.viewAnimator.setLayoutAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", "Animation end -> " + viewAnimator.getDisplayedChild());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

But the above is not working.

Answer (score 0):

> public void setLayoutAnimationListener (Animation.AnimationListener
>   animationListener)
>
> Specifies the animation listener to which layout animation events must
>   be sent.

I guess you want to listen animation child of `ViewAnimator`, if I'm right:

Your code are listening animation of `ViewGroup` in this case is `ViewAnimator` but not it's child

Try this solution if you need:

```
slideInRightFast.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"START",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"END",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"REPEAT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Wish it can help you. Sorry my bad English.